# Custom URL rewrites for templates

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite some URLs to custom templates. For example, I have a page at domain.com/page, and when a user clicks 'remove' on an element, it goes to domain.com/page/?remove=54. I'd like it to rewrite to domain.com/page/remove/54.

Help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi *@Gavin*: Can you clarify your question?  Where is this *'remove'* that the user clicks on? What code is creating the link? Is your code creating this link? What are you removing? *(I know it's not "important" for the question but it helps me understand what you are trying to do.)* OR are you saying you want to have URLs of the format `/page/remove/54` and you want the 54 to be accessible in your theme using `$_GET['remove']` on the page normally loaded by the `/page/` URL?

Comment: There are several functions that are going to be using url variables - for instance, one removes an event created by a custom plugin. User clicks an 'x', and the link goes to `?remove=346`, for example. You're spot on, what I need is the URL to appear clean (`remove/346`) but for `$_GET['remove']` to be accessible within the page template. Does that help? Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to add something to the end of every post/page rewrite rule, you probably can just add a *rewrite endpoint*. These are regexes of the form `/[endpoint_name](/[optional_extra_stuff])?` that are appended to the already generated rules for pages, posts, archives, ...

You define on which structures you want to add them by setting the *endpoint mask*. This is a bitmask, so you can combine different groups using the `|` operator, like this: `EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES` will match for every page and every permalink (full post and date-based archives). The default list of endpoints can be found [at the top of `wp-includes/rewrite.php`.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.2/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L96)

The following code will add `/remove(/(.*))?` to the existing rewrite rules for pages, posts and date-based archives (for some reason they are generated twice, once in `EP_PERMALINK` and once in `EP_DATE`). `remove` will also be available as a public query var, so you can do `$wp_query->get( 'remove' )` to get the value (if set) of the `[optional_extra_stuff]` in the URL.

```
add_filter( 'init', 'wpse2614_init' );
function wpse2614_init()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'remove', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is totally simple. In you PHP script where you output the `?remove=54` just output `remove/54` instead. That should do the job to change the links as you asked for.

Comment: I think Gavin has no problems changing the links, but "catching" the new request. If you have a WordPress page at `/pagetitle`, a request for `/pagetitle/remove/54` won't give you that without changing the rewrite structure.

Comment: Well, I can not read that exactly in his question. But if so, he could register "remove" as an rewrite endpoint: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API